# My master bedroom is hot! Should I install a return in my master bedroom?

Tags: hvac

Thanks for taking the time to read my question. I have a house where the master bedroom was added in during an expansion. The master sits half above unfinished basement and half above crawlspace and has a single floor vent to draw air from the central air system.

My room is sweltering in the summer and frigid in the winter while the rest of the upstairs is quite comfy and I'm, frankly, quite tired of it. After around two years of google-fu and thought I've decided to fix it and I think the problem would be solved by adding a return into the master.

Is this the case? If so, where would be a good place to start and learn how to add returns. If not, is there something else that would fix the problem?

I can provide further information upon request and, again, thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is thanks. A return duct will help the air flow into the room when the door is closed. Up sizing the supply and dampers to to help provide more flow may also help. In my last home I had 2 dampers that I adjusted 1 for up stairs and 1 for down. More air to the upstairs in summer when it was cold and more down in the winter when the heat was on. Since both seasons are not comfortable a return would be the first change then an upsize to the supply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a good resource to start with on installing returns?

Comment: I have not used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sipols.rapidhvacductsizing.free&hl=en) it is a free duct sizing calculator for your phone. I have a plastic calculator that has disks that rotate I think it cost 20$ many years ago, I would go with free.